# Axiom of Choice and Probability

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

let $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,... \}$. 
Set $\Omega = \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and define for every $\omega \in  \Omega$
\begin{equation}
Y_n (\omega) = \omega_n.
\end{equation}
Then Williams, Probability with Martingales, states without proof the following
fact: if the axiom of choice holds, then there
exists no probability measure defined on
*all* the subsets of $\Omega$ 
such that the random variables $Y_n$
are IID.
Do you have some idea of the proof?
Any hint is well accepted.
Thank you very much for your help.
My best regards,
Maurizio Barbato

Comment: I think that this is related to the fact that if we give $\mathbb{N}$ the discrete topology, then the set $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ the compact open topology,  then we get a space that is homeomorphic to the irrational numbers. This http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/irrational+number seems helpful.

Comment: I think http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set should get your started. There is actually an article on this in the current (Aug.-Sep. 2013) issue of The American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: I know Vitali's example, but I can't see how to use his reasoning in this setting. We should be able to define a group structure on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ such that the probability measure induced by the fact that $Y_n$ are IID is translation invariant with respect to the group operation.

Comment: This is not strictly true: let the measure be a point mass at $(1,1,1,\dots)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a paper which gives the proof
in the case of the space $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$.
Once you identify $\mathbb{N}$ to
$\mathbb{Z}$ through a bijection (so
to identify $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to
$\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{Z}$), the proof
given in the paper goes through without
changes.

The paper is the following:
Holroyd & Soo, A Nonmeasurable Set from
Coin Flips, The American Mathematical
Monthly, vol. 116, n. 10, 2009.

Thank you very much for your attention.
Best Regards,
Maurizio Barbato

Comment: Glad to see that you found the answer. It would be of help to the community if you augmented the reference with (an outline of) the proof given.